# adding a field to a user after created

Tags: meteor

This code attempts to add a field to a user which already exist in meteor users.
The error I am getting is

> Exception while invoking method 'logMeIn' Error: insert requires an argument

Which I don't understand, how can it be fixed? Thanks

```
/////////////////////////////////////
//       client code
/////////////////////////////////////
Template.login.events({
  'click #logMe': function() {
    var username = $('#id').val();
    var password = $('#pin').val();
    Meteor.call('logMeIn', [username,password], function (err, data) {  //create new user
      if ( err ) {
        if (err.message.match(/username already exists/i)) {
          Meteor.loginWithPassword(username+password,password)
        }
      } else {
        console.log('new user created');
      }
    });
  }
});

/////////////////////////////////////
//       server code
/////////////////////////////////////

Meteor.methods({
  logMeIn: function (credentials) {
    //do work , if logged in, do next line
    var idPin = credentials[0] + credentials[1];
    Accounts.createUser({username: idPin, password: credentials[1]});
  }
});


Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  user.menuGroup = 'a';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `user` on the Account.onCreatedUser (documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)). Also, additional data of the user should be put under the `profile` branch (check the documentation in [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser))

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  if (options.profile) {
      user.profile = options.profile;
  } 

  if (user['profile'] == null) {
      user['profile'] = {};
  }

  user['profile']['menuGroup'] = 'a';
  return user;
});
```

Comment: that gives; TypeError: Cannot set property 'menuGroup' of undefined